# how Can I change colors of Nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I create a simple graphe in neo4j , i woulde like to change the colors of differents nodes to differentiate between the nodes that have the same label .
how can i do it !
[click here to see the graphe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cS8v.png)

Answer (score 0):

From Neo4j desktop; click on the Node then at the bottom, you will see the color or size that you want for that node.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could [style the Graph using the GraSS file](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-styling/#grass).
After you have made the desired changes in the result pane, run the ':style' command and export the existing style as a GraSS file.

[image: Export GraSS File]

You could modify the style file using a text editor if needed.
But most importantly, You could just drag and drop it into an existing neo4j browser session. This way, you can reapply the same style between different browser sessions instantly, without having to modify them manually each time.